# Create hotkey setting area using NSTextField?

Tags: xcode, swift, macos

I'd like to create a text field that captures a user's key input, including modifier keys, and displays it as a key combination. I'd basically like exactly what's shown in Xcode's Interface Builder:
[image: Xcode IB]

What's the best way to do this, and how would I access the value to set as a button's key equivalent?

Comment: There are a handful of third-party libraries to do this. Search for "Shortcut Recorder".

Comment: @jtbandes I'd prefer to do it natively, if at all possible.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "natively". You could write it yourself, but you'd be much better off using ShortcutRecorder.

Comment: I meant whatever way it's done in Xcode.

Comment: The "Apple way," I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MASShortcut](https://github.com/shpakovski/MASShortcut) worked great for this exact problem.

The documentation is thorough but basically an MASShortcutView handles all of this for you and returns a `keyEquivalent` as well as `modifierFlags` to set for your `NSButton/NSMenuItem/NSTextField`/etc.